# Good article or book to q-analogs?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, reference-request, q-analogs

I want to learn more about the following Topics:

- $q$-analog calculus
- what can be done with the $q$-Pochhammer Symbol
- applications of $q$-analogs in combinatorics

However, I have found very Little that answers These questions comprehensively. Are there some books or good articles where These Topics are explained?

Every reply will be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't studied these very much, but Frederico spends about 2 hours talking about them in his Enumerative Combinatorics lectures. He defines them and shows the analogs of the factorial and binomial coefficients at the tail end of [this lecture](http://youtu.be/0tRDLURozak?t=39m41s) and then in [the next lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBNBd8DlocI) he proves that the number of k-dimensional subspaces of a finite vector space $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ is the q-binomial coefficient [n,k]$_q$.

Answer (score 3):

The bible of $q$-analysis from which I learned the subject is Basis Hypergeometric Series of Gasper and Rahman. It spends some parts on applications in combinatorics.

The book Special Functions of Andrews, Askey and Roy spends a chapter an introduction on $q$-analysis. This is also worth reading.

Be warned that the context of the book Basic Hypergeometric Series is rather dense. It is very hard to read it from cover to cover. If you study $q$-analogues it's often a good idea to also study the classical case too. This makes it much easier to understand what's going on in the $q$-case.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend "Quantum Calculus" (by Kac and Cheung, published by Springer) and "A Comprehensive Treatment of $q$-Calculus" (by Ernst, published by Springer) to understand $q$-calculus. These books include basic tools of $q$-calculus (fundamental theorem of $q$-calculus, $q$-chain rule, $q$-integration by parts, $q$-Taylor formula, etc.).

I wish that you enjoy the $q$-world!